# Angular Build <script> tags have type="module" using build-angular 13.1.2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-builder

How can I disable this and revert back to a script tag that doesn't expect to be a module?

I've tried changing the tsconfig.json to have a target of es5 and that does not work.

Comment: Why is that a problem? It's Angular generated code, it's probably like that for a reason.

Comment: Because the browser won't load the scripts as modules if they are running on a file:// URL, and I need them to.

Comment: And why would you need that? You should probably use ng serve

Comment: If I had another way to do I I would, I work at a business and that’s the way they load files.

Comment: You need to explain further. Is that for a dev environment? Then just use ng serve. For production, get a proper webserver and don't try to solve problems that are created by your other problems.

Comment: I work for a company that provides digital signage, the way the core platform works there is no server ran for any local html content. Unfortunately changing that in the short term is not an option. I’ve been about to use angular in previous project, however after updating to the latest CLI I can’t seem to get it to build without the type=module in the script tag.

Comment: @Clashsoft not being out of topic here, just curious, angular use webpack, and webpack can't output es module, how does angular output es module?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default behavior for script tag by adding custom webpack config in your Angular project by following the below instructions:

1. Add a js file called webpack.config.js in the root of your project.
2. Add below content in the webpack.config.js file

```js
module.export = {
  output: {
scriptType: 'text/javascript'
}
}
```

3. Install @angular-builders/custom-webpack in your angular project as the dev dependency using the below command

```
npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack --save-dev
```

4. In your angular.json file, find and modify the configurations to build your application using the webpack.config.js that you created in step 1.

```
...
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
...
customWebpackConfig": {
"path": "webpack.config.js"
...
}
...
}
}
```

This will allow you, mainly the step 2 to output the Angular build  tags to have type="text/javascript" instead of module. Suggest you to go through below links to get more understanding about the webpack configuration that I have suggested above and to build angular project using custom webpack configurations:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputscripttype
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack